# How to set song from MediaLibrary as Alarm sound in WindowsPhone8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I need to add Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.Song from MediaLibrary into Microsoft.Phone.Scheduler.Alarm.  It requires an uri to the song. But there is no 'uri' field in the Song class. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, that your song is in your application's package (included in project files). Then you can directly create an Uri to this MP3 file, without needing to deal with the XNA's Song class.

Example:

```
alarm.Sound = new Uri("/Assets/MyAlarm.mp3", UriKind.Relative);
```

I assume here, that your MP3 file is included in the Assets folder and has build action set to Content.

Please note, that only MP3, WMA and WAV are allowed. Also, you can't play sounds from Isolated Storage, they must reside inside your project.

Comment: Thank you very much! But I mean class Song from MediaLibrary.

Comment: I'm afraid I will have to disappoint you, because that is not possible now (at least in no way I know about). The Alarm accepts only local music files from app package. I expect it could be possible in upcoming release of Windows Phone, but now it is apparently a no-go.